# Find $m$ so that $\mbox{rank} \left( A^{-1} \right) = 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 3  & m \\ 3 & 4 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ Find $m$ so that $\text{rank} \left(A^{-1}\right)=3$

---

Please help me with this problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: And remember that the key for this question is to find $m$ such that $A$ is invertible, is you find such $m$ it must be that $A^{-1}$ is also invertible, namely full rank, namely $rank(A^{-1}) = 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is the order of the largest non-singular matrix. If the rank of matrix $A^{-1} = 3$, $\det{A} \neq 0$
$$\because \det{A} = 4-4m \ne 0 \implies m \neq 1$$
If I have made some error, please feel free to correct me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry! I fixed the error :)